# Determine whether or not data from SQL data-source has the same value

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I'm currently building a GUI that is importing data from a SQL server.

I'm currently using ComboBox's to allow the user to pick the Category/Sub_Category he would like to access. > [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zw1zb.png)

I cannot figure out how to determine whether or not the data located in the row for the Category column has the same values, and if they do, whether or not they have a Sub_Category listed.

[DataRow Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5iHLd.png)

The Sub_Categories should only Sync with their corresponding Categories, not all Categories, so I need to come up with a way to pair the sub_categories and categories together.

If no Sub_Category(s) exist for the WHOLE Category, then the Sub_Category_ComboBox should be set to non-editable (IsEditable = false), since their would be no value for it.

If a category does contain a Sub_Category, then SubCategory_ComboBox should display only the Sub_Categories that are Sync'd to the specific Category(s).
(Not sure how to sync them yet either).

DDL:

```
--------------------------## Heading ##------------------------------
--  DDL for Table OP_MAIN_COLLECTIONS
--------------------------------------------------------

  CREATE TABLE "SCHEMA"."OP_MAIN_COLLECTIONS" 
   (    "PRIMARY_KEY" NUMBER(*,0), 
    "CATEGORY" VARCHAR2(4000 CHAR), 
    "SUB_CATEGORY" VARCHAR2(4000 CHAR), 
    "NAME" VARCHAR2(4000 CHAR), 
    "SCHEDULE" CLOB, 
    "INTERNAL_NAME" VARCHAR2(4000 CHAR), 
    "COMMENTS" CLOB, 
    "START_DATE" DATE, 
    "END_DATE" DATE, 
    "SCHEDULED_OR_UNSCHEDULED" NUMBER(*,0)
   ) SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
  PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 
 NOCOMPRESS LOGGING
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "SCHEMA" 
 LOB ("SCHEDULE") STORE AS BASICFILE "SYS_LOB0000315099C00005$$"(
  TABLESPACE "SCHEMA" ENABLE STORAGE IN ROW CHUNK 8192 RETENTION 
  NOCACHE LOGGING 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)) 
 LOB ("COMMENTS") STORE AS BASICFILE (
  TABLESPACE "SCHEMA" ENABLE STORAGE IN ROW CHUNK 8192 RETENTION 
  NOCACHE LOGGING 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)) ;

   COMMENT ON COLUMN "SCHEMA"."OP_MAIN_COLLECTIONS"."PRIMARY_KEY" IS 'PK as INT';
   COMMENT ON COLUMN "SCHEMA"."OP_MAIN_COLLECTIONS"."CATEGORY" IS 'A Category will only display if the user has the proper rights/privledges to read it, as will all data within'' a category.';
   COMMENT ON COLUMN "SCHEMA"."OP_MAIN_COLLECTIONS"."SUB_CATEGORY" IS 'Column (Variable) that allows for sub_categories to exist. Can be Null.';
   COMMENT ON COLUMN "SCHEMA"."OP_MAIN_COLLECTIONS"."NAME" IS 'Name of Operation: Limited to 50 Characters atm';
   COMMENT ON COLUMN "SCHEMA"."OP_MAIN_COLLECTIONS"."SCHEDULE" IS 'Schedule EX: "5AM - 11PM(ET), EVERY 30 MINUTES*, MON THRU SUN" (Can end up being rather large so made it a clob).';
   COMMENT ON COLUMN "SCHEMA"."OP_MAIN_COLLECTIONS"."INTERNAL_NAME" IS 'Job_Name set to VarChar(120)';
   COMMENT ON COLUMN "SCHEMA"."OP_MAIN_COLLECTIONS"."COMMENTS" IS 'Any job comments that may exist will be located here. May be rather large, so it was made a CLOB just incase.';
   COMMENT ON COLUMN "SCHEMA"."OP_MAIN_COLLECTIONS"."START_DATE" IS 'Start Date variable that allows for Procedure to be hidden until date set.';
   COMMENT ON COLUMN "SCHEMA"."OP_MAIN_COLLECTIONS"."END_DATE" IS 'End Date variable that allows for Procedure to be Removed once the date listed is reached.';
   COMMENT ON COLUMN "SCHEMA"."OP_MAIN_COLLECTIONS"."SCHEDULED_OR_UNSCHEDULED" IS 'Neccessary Information to determine whether or not the event has been scheduled or not. (Limited to a value of 0 or 1). - If 0, unscheduled | if 1, scheduled.';
--------------------------------------------------------
--  DDL for Index OP_SCHEDULED_PK
--------------------------------------------------------

  CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "SCHEMA"."OP_SCHEDULED_PK" ON "SCHEMA"."OP_MAIN_COLLECTIONS" ("PRIMARY_KEY") 
  PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS 
  STORAGE( INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "SCHEMA" ;
  ALTER INDEX "SCHEMA"."OP_SCHEDULED_PK"  UNUSABLE;
--------------------------------------------------------
--  Constraints for Table OP_MAIN_COLLECTIONS
--------------------------------------------------------

  ALTER TABLE "SCHEMA"."OP_MAIN_COLLECTIONS" MODIFY ("SCHEDULED_OR_UNSCHEDULED" NOT NULL ENABLE);
  ALTER TABLE "SCHEMA"."OP_MAIN_COLLECTIONS" ADD CONSTRAINT "SCHEDULED_OR_UNSCHEDULED" CHECK (SCHEDULED_OR_UNSCHEDULED >= 0 AND SCHEDULED_OR_UNSCHEDULED < 2) ENABLE;
  ALTER TABLE "SCHEMA"."OP_MAIN_COLLECTIONS" ADD CONSTRAINT "OP_SCHEDULED_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("PRIMARY_KEY")
  USING INDEX PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS 
  STORAGE( INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "SCHEMA" 
  ALTER INDEX "SCHEMA"."OP_SCHEDULED_PK"  UNUSABLE; ENABLE;
  ALTER TABLE "SCHEMA"."OP_MAIN_COLLECTIONS" MODIFY ("COMMENTS" NOT NULL ENABLE);
  ALTER TABLE "SCHEMA"."OP_MAIN_COLLECTIONS" MODIFY ("INTERNAL_NAME" NOT NULL ENABLE);
  ALTER TABLE "SCHEMA"."OP_MAIN_COLLECTIONS" MODIFY ("SCHEDULE" NOT NULL ENABLE);
  ALTER TABLE "SCHEMA"."OP_MAIN_COLLECTIONS" MODIFY ("NAME" NOT NULL ENABLE);
  ALTER TABLE "SCHEMA"."OP_MAIN_COLLECTIONS" MODIFY ("CATEGORY" NOT NULL ENABLE);
  ALTER TABLE "SCHEMA"."OP_MAIN_COLLECTIONS" MODIFY ("PRIMARY_KEY" NOT NULL ENABLE);
--------------------------------------------------------
--  Ref Constraints for Table OP_MAIN_COLLECTIONS
--------------------------------------------------------

  ALTER TABLE "SCHEMA"."OP_MAIN_COLLECTIONS" ADD CONSTRAINT "CATEGORY" FOREIGN KEY ("PRIMARY_KEY")
      REFERENCES "SCHEMA"."OP_MAIN_COLLECTIONS" ("PRIMARY_KEY") ENABLE;
--------------------------------------------------------
--  DDL for Trigger AUD_UPDATE
--------------------------------------------------------

  CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER "SCHEMA"."AUD_UPDATE" 
after update on OP_MAIN_COLLECTIONS
for each row
begin
    AUDIT_PACKAGE.check_val( 'OP_MAIN_COLLECTIONS', 'PRIMARY_KEY', :new.PRIMARY_KEY, :old.PRIMARY_KEY);
    AUDIT_PACKAGE.check_val( 'OP_MAIN_COLLECTIONS', 'CATEGORY', :new.CATEGORY, :old.CATEGORY);
    AUDIT_PACKAGE.check_val( 'OP_MAIN_COLLECTIONS', 'SUB_CATEGORY', :new.SUB_CATEGORY, :old.SUB_CATEGORY);
    AUDIT_PACKAGE.check_val( 'OP_MAIN_COLLECTIONS', 'NAME', :new.NAME, :old.NAME);
    AUDIT_PACKAGE.check_val( 'OP_MAIN_COLLECTIONS', 'SCHEDULE', :new.SCHEDULE, :old.SCHEDULE);
    AUDIT_PACKAGE.check_val( 'OP_MAIN_COLLECTIONS', 'INTERNAL_NAME', :new.INTERNAL_NAME, :old.INTERNAL_NAME);
    AUDIT_PACKAGE.check_val( 'OP_MAIN_COLLECTIONS', 'COMMENTS', :new.COMMENTS, :old.COMMENTS);
    AUDIT_PACKAGE.check_val( 'OP_MAIN_COLLECTIONS', 'START_DATE', :new.START_DATE, :old.START_DATE);
    AUDIT_PACKAGE.check_val( 'OP_MAIN_COLLECTIONS', 'END_DATE', :new.END_DATE, :old.END_DATE);
    AUDIT_PACKAGE.check_val( 'OP_MAIN_COLLECTIONS', 'SCHEDULED_OR_UNSCHEDULED', :new.SCHEDULED_OR_UNSCHEDULED, :old.SCHEDULED_OR_UNSCHEDULED);
end;
/
ALTER TRIGGER "SCHEMA"."AUD_UPDATE" ENABLE;
```

C#:

```
/*
* What we're trying to do:
* 
* First, determine whether or not the row(s) data for the Category column have data for the Sub_Category column or if the Category data contains the same values (names, EX: BillTrak Pro), then sort them accordingly.
** Sub_Categories should only Sync with their corresponding Categories, not all Categories.
* 
* 
* Conditionals for the Category data pertaining to Sub_Category(s):
** If no Sub_Category(s) exist for the WHOLE Category, then > Sub_Category_ComboBox should be set to read ONLY(IsEnabled = false) and the four ListView's should just display single Category Information.
* 
* 
** If Category(s) contain Sub_Category(s), then SubCategory_ComboBox should display only the Sub_Categories that are Sync'd to the specific Category(s).
* Row Data should be sorted, first by Category, then Sub_Category, then displayed only when their Sub_Category is displayed via the SubCategory_ComboBox.
* The four ListView's data should only display data, coresponding to the SubCategory_ComboBox data.
* 
*/


namespace WpfApplication1
{
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {

        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

WpfApplication1.DataSet1 dataSet1 = ((WpfApplication1.DataSet1)(this.FindResource("dataSet1")));
        // Load data into the table OP_MAIN_COLLECTIONS. You can modify this code as needed.
        WpfApplication1.DataSet1TableAdapters.OP_MAIN_COLLECTIONSTableAdapter dataSet1OP_MAIN_COLLECTIONSTableAdapter = new WpfApplication1.DataSet1TableAdapters.OP_MAIN_COLLECTIONSTableAdapter();
        dataSet1OP_MAIN_COLLECTIONSTableAdapter.Fill(dataSet1.OP_MAIN_COLLECTIONS);
        System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource oP_MAIN_COLLECTIONSViewSource = ((System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource)(this.FindResource("oP_MAIN_COLLECTIONSViewSource")));
        oP_MAIN_COLLECTIONSViewSource.View.MoveCurrentToFirst();
        WpfApplication1.DataSet2 dataSet2 = ((WpfApplication1.DataSet2)(this.FindResource("dataSet2")));
        // Load data into the table OP_TITLE_INFORMATION. You can modify this code as needed.
        WpfApplication1.DataSet2TableAdapters.OP_TITLE_INFORMATIONTableAdapter dataSet2OP_TITLE_INFORMATIONTableAdapter = new WpfApplication1.DataSet2TableAdapters.OP_TITLE_INFORMATIONTableAdapter();
        dataSet2OP_TITLE_INFORMATIONTableAdapter.Fill(dataSet2.OP_TITLE_INFORMATION);
        System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource oP_TITLE_INFORMATIONViewSource = ((System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource)(this.FindResource("oP_TITLE_INFORMATIONViewSource")));
        oP_TITLE_INFORMATIONViewSource.View.MoveCurrentToFirst();
        // Load data into the table OP_MAIN_COLLECTIONS. You can modify this code as needed.
        WpfApplication1.DataSet2TableAdapters.OP_MAIN_COLLECTIONSTableAdapter dataSet2OP_MAIN_COLLECTIONSTableAdapter = new WpfApplication1.DataSet2TableAdapters.OP_MAIN_COLLECTIONSTableAdapter();
        dataSet2OP_MAIN_COLLECTIONSTableAdapter.Fill(dataSet2.OP_MAIN_COLLECTIONS);
        System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource oP_MAIN_COLLECTIONSViewSource1 = ((System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource)(this.FindResource("oP_MAIN_COLLECTIONSViewSource1")));
        oP_MAIN_COLLECTIONSViewSource1.View.MoveCurrentToFirst();
    }

    /**
     * Operations Guide Name Display settings.
     */
    private void OPGuideName_textBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    /**
     * Category_ComboBox Display settings.
     */
    private void Category_ComboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        /**
         * TO-DO:
         * Determine whether or not the row(s) data for the Category column have data for the Sub_Category column
         * or if the Category data contains the same values (names, EX: BillTrak Pro), then sort them accordingly.
         */

        int id = 1; //Get form category combox
        WpfApplication1.DataSet2 DS = ((WpfApplication1.DataSet2)(this.FindResource("dataSet2")));

        var cats = DS.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().Select(r => new { Key = r.Field<int>("Primary_Key"), Category = r.Field<string>("Category") }).ToList();

        foreach( var cat in cats)
        {
            //Add category and primary key to combo box
            Category_ComboBox.Items.Add(new { cat.Key, cat.Category } );
        }

        DataRow row = DS.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().Where(r => r.Field<int>("Id") == id).FirstOrDefault();

        if (row != default(DataRow))
        {
            if (row["sub_category"] != DBNull.Value)
            {
                //There is a sub category
            }
            else
            {
                //sub category is null
            }
            }
            else
            {
                //selected category id does not exists
            }
    }


    /**
     * SubCategory_ComboBox Display settings.
     */
    private void SubCategory_ComboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        /**
         * Purpose:
         * Should convert SubCategory_ComboBox to readOnly(IsEnabled = false)
         * if the data contained in the SubCategory SQL Column is null && Category doesn't contain any Sub_Categories.
         * Else, display SubCategory_ComboBox as normal, sync'd with the corresponding category name.
         * 
         * Currently, This code disables the subcategory combobox completely.
         * Need to figure out how to get it to read ONLY the null data, not the entire column.
         */
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(SubCategory_ComboBox.Text))
        {
            SubCategory_ComboBox.IsEnabled = false;
        }
    }

    private void sCHEDULEListView_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {

    }

}
}
```

Comment: Are you having trouble writing sql? Or, you already got the data in the form of datareader/dataset and having trouble how to filter?

Comment: Already have the SQL written, now, I'm trying to figure out how to filter out the data. As per, determine whether or not the same Category name exists & then how to deal with the subCategories. - I'm presuming this part should be done in Visual Studio (C#), not the SQL Database.

Comment: Could you please post the sql query and c# code so that other members can look and help you?

Comment: Is that what you need? ^.^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following template when your `Category_ComboBox_SelectionChanged` is fired to determine if sub category exists or not. You can check the name also if provided from user input.

```
var cats = DS.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().Select(r => new { Key = r.Field<int>("Primary_Key"), Category = r.Field<string>("Category") }).ToList();

        foreach( var cat in cats)
        {
            //Add category and primary key to combo box
            //combox.addItem(cat.Key, cat.Category)
        }

        int id = 1; //Get form category combox
        DataSet DS = new DataSet(); // your dataset


        DataRow row = DS.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().Where(r => r.Field<int>("Id") == id).FirstOrDefault();

        if (row != default(DataRow))
        {
            if (row["sub_category"] != DBNull.Value)
            {
                //There is a sub category
            }
            else
            {
                //sub category is null
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //selected category id does not exists
        }
```

Hope it helps!!

**EDIT**

```
//find all categories and populate category
        IEnumerable<string> categories = DS.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().Select(r => r.Field<string>("Category")).Distinct();


        //once the value in category combobox change 

        // inside Category_ComboBox_SelectionChanged
        string category = "Bill";

        //get rows with non null sub categories
        IEnumerable<DataRow> rows = DS.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().Where(r => r.Field<string>("Category").ToLower() == category.ToLower() && r["Sub_Category"] != DBNull.Value);

        if (rows.Count() == 0)
        {
            //disable sub category
        }
        else 
        {
            //get sub categories
            IEnumerable<string> sub_cats = rows.Select(r => r.Field<string>("Sub_category")).Distinct();

            //populate sub categories
        }
```

EDIT

Populate category using this loop

```
foreach (DataRow row in DS.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            int primary_key = row.Field<int>("Primary_Key");
            string category = row.Field<string>("Category");

            //populate the combo box
        }
```

Comment: Okay, I got it setting to non-editable/editable dependant on the sub-category being there or not. However, I can not figure out how to get Category / Sub_Category combobox to sync and limit the view in terms of data that is being displayed. <-- | Two rows have the Category of the name, "Bill", with one having a subcat of "Smith" and the other "Cat" >> The only data that should display in the Sub_Category combobox should be "Smith" and "Cat", not the other subcategories that are shown via the other categories/rows. - If that makes sense. o.O - Updated my main post with what I have so far.

Comment: The code you updated won't work. I thought you are searching by Id not category name, sorry. I have updated the answer that will help you enable/disable sub category box as well as sync between category and sub category.

Comment: When implementing the edition, putting "SubCategory_ComboBox.IsEnabled = false;" in the if(rows.count() ==0), will disable everything upon startup of the GUI and remain that way for every option whether a sub_Category is listed or not | if I put that in the else portion, it won't disable it upon startup, but any option selected will then disable the sub_category box indefinitely. The way I have currently in the main post will disable and un-disable correctly, but it's backwards logic. Haha. Kinda stumped here.

Comment: Well the above code just explains how you can sync between category and sub-category. I believe, you can different code block to display initial GUI. If one initial display, there is no category selected, then sub category will be disabled. If there is a category selected, then you would run the above code again to display sub categories. In the else case above, you would have to enable the sub_category box.

Comment: Edited the initial post with what I currently have. Right now, it's working as it seems it should with the disable portion of what I'm trying to do, but it still looks like the code itself is working opposite of what it should be.

Comment: What do you mean by 'code itself is working opposite'?

Comment: It looks like what it's doing, is updating the GUI, after each option is clicked. | So, Let's say, an option that should be row.count() == 1; is actually displaying what would be row.count() == 2 and vise-versa | Making it so that I have to manipulate the code to be more of a cheaphax in order to get it to display correctly.

Comment: That because you did `rows.Count() != 1`. Sub category exists when `rows.count() > 0`.

Comment: Well, the rows.Count isn't working like that. | I have it printing out the row.Count each graphical update | Initial startup of the program = Prints out 0 | First category (Has a subcat) click = prints 1 | Second Category (Doesn't have a subcat) click = prints 2. | Third Category (Has a subcat) = prints 2. <-- So, it's not being disabled. Any idea about why that is?

Comment: it shouldn't do that. Could you please update the code to see what is happening?

Comment: Updated main post.

Comment: Then it is working as it supposed to. Let me ask this - according to the image you have posted, what are the options you are displaying in Category combo-box? - is it one 'test' or 4 'test'?

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/xy9U2Wb.png & http://i.imgur.com/3cDEC2B.png | Both of these combo-box's should be working together. So, if "BillTrak Pro" is displayed - Every ROW containing the category 'BillTrak Pro' should be searched for a sub_category | The sub_category combo-box should then display only the subcategories listed for that specific category. | If the category, such as the first 'test' category' listed, doesn't contain any sub_categories, then the sub_category box should be disabled. (Set to isEnabled=false).

Comment: I think we are talking in circles here my friend. If you are populating all the 'test' in the category dropdown, you should also put the primary key of that category (in the combo box) and search the dataset with that primary key (my initial code). if you are populating with only one 'test', the code is working correctly then. On a side note, how would a user know which 'test' to select?

Comment: This GUI is an operations guide for people to be able to go through and read whatever category > sub_category they may need to in order to clarify what to do on a certain instance for our website. >> Let's say we have the following data: http://i.imgur.com/F2qKKFd.png | BillTrak Pro located in ROW 1 & 3, both have the same Sub_Category, where as ROW 4, while in the same Category, contains a seperate Sub_Category > Both of those categories, are the only things that should display in the sub_category combobox if the Category > BillTrak Pro is displayed. (Meaning, I must also find a way to limit)

Comment: (Meaning I must also find a way to limit the same category name from displaying) > I confused as to how the primary key fits into this (I'm very new with working on SQL, sorry for the dumb questions). > I hope I'm starting to make more sense as to what I'm trying to accomplish..

Comment: Can user also do an operation when sub category is null?

Comment: No, if the sub_category is null, then the category data should just display in the information boxes below said combobox's. > EX: http://i.imgur.com/NosjH98.png    (Note, disabled sub_category strictly to show the example - since their is a sub_category, it should actually be enabled...) <--> (Also need to figure out how to limit each row from displaying in these ListViews and only displaying the selected data corresponding with the category > sub_category).

Comment: Okay. Let's go through this one more time. With the help of category and sub category, we want user to select a particular row. if you are displaying distinct categories, when user selects a category, you (as a programmer) cannot know if the sub category exists or not. The second option is to display all the categories (the text will duplicate) but the combo box value for that option would be primary key of that row. if user selects a particular one, you would check if that row has sub category or not. Not it depends how you want the user to select a particular row!! Hope this helps

Comment: Yes. I believe the second options would be the best end-result then at this point.

Comment: Updated the post (before EDIT) for how you can get each category with corresponding primary key.

Comment: Getting a cast issue with this line:  var cats = DS.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().Select(r => new { Key = r.Field<int>("Primary_Key"), Category = r.Field<string>("Category") }).ToList();

Comment: could you post the cast exception?

Comment: that exception is not telling me anything... added an edit how you can loop the dataset to populate the category combo-box.

Comment: The Cast exception has to do with Primary_key, as it doesn't work DataRow row either. Is there any way to get VS console to display all the details of an exception? | The exception handler is only giving minimal details. | It's almost as if it's not reading Primary_Key as an int, which wouldn't make sense.

Comment: what is the data type of your Primary_Key column? If it is string, change the `row.field<int>("Primary_key")` to `row.field<string>("Primary_Key")`

Comment: Tried that, got : "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Decimal' to type 'System.String'." > So I'm presuming it's indeed a int.

Comment: well, decimal and int are different. You should change the primary key column to int. or try this - `decimal primary_key = row.Field<decimal>("Primary_Key");`

Comment: Decimal worked. For some reason, SQLDeveloper won't let me change it from Dec. > Integer. | Anyways, Since the data is currently being drawn in from the SQL datasource, Category_ComboBox.Items.Add(new { cat.Key, cat.Category } ); will not work > I am presuming I'll have to do something similar to this:                                        Category_ComboBox.ItemsSource = Enum.GetValues(typeof()).Cast<>(); | or I could just remove itemsource? Which way would be better?. ---- http://i.imgur.com/98vWG7c.png

Comment: sorry. I am not familiar with WPF controls. Probably you could ask another question on SO on how to modify combo-boxes. If you think your original problem has been resolved (sync category and sub category), you can mark this question as answered.